# razor blade with final cut pro X, duplicate instead of cut my plan

Tags: finalcut

when I used the razor blade, it multiply my plan by two instead of making a cut where I need on the plan ?

Something about the settings ?

Someone has an idea ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

No matter what version of application you are using FCP7 or FCPX, the reason for such unpredictable behaviour of the app is a bug. Seemingly it's internal error of mp4 structure, unless you accidentally move a content inside a clip with a Slip Tool.

Or you have accidentally applied <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (Paste) command instead <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> (Blade Tool) on your keyboard.

Or you've made a copy of a clip pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+LMB while dragging.